# Context#currentProcessingTime in Flink CEP

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-cep

When using Flink CEP `Context`s have `currentProcessingTime` property. Is there a difference between using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and this method? Here's a small experiment and it seems that these values are mostly equal (at least in this simplistic scenario).

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val source = env.fromCollection((1 to 100000).map(_ => 1).toList)

val pattern = Pattern.begin[Int]("start")
    .where(new IterativeCondition[Int] {
      override def filter(value: Int, ctx: IterativeCondition.Context[Int]): Boolean = {
        ctx.currentProcessingTime == System.currentTimeMillis
      }
    })

CEP.pattern(source, pattern)
    .process[Int]((m, ctx, out) => m.get("start").forEach(out.collect(_)))
    .keyBy(_ => "")
    .reduce(_ + _)
    .print() // sometimes less than 100000

env.execute()
```

The only reason I can think of is that `currentProcessingTimestamp` is somehow consistent across many machines / parallel operator instances?

Answer (score 2):

`currentProcessingTime` is just a wrapper around `System.currentTimeMillis`. It's not doing anything clever.